Scrolling Notifications stuck in "Raw HTML" element of consulting theme
I am using consutling wordpress theme for builing a simple website. In that I need to display scrolling news . These news are basically a specific type of posts within wordpress. To achieve this I have created a webpage "ajax2.html" in which I am calling a "getNotifs.php"  . When I open this ajax2.html from a browser directly https://example.com/ajax2.html it is displaying the scrolling news . However when I paste this code in a "Raw Html" type of element of consulting theme, then it just display 1st news item of scrolling news and then it gets stuck. I am totalling confused why it is not working. Can someone please help me to display the scrolling news in wordpress Raw HTML or even Raw Javascript element. Any other suggestions to display a "specific type" of wordpress posts as SCROLLING News. Here I am also pasting the actual getNotifs.php down below. Thanks in advance
Here is my ajax2.html code
***************************
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scrolling Announcements</title> <!-- FUNCTION TO LOAD EXTERNAL php-->
    <script>
        function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
                        this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/getNotifs.php", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        /* Style for the scrolling container */
        .announcement-container {
            height: 200px;
            /* Set the desired height for the scrolling area */
            overflow: hidden;
            /* Hide overflow content */
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        /* Style for the scrolling text */
        .announcement-text {
            animation: scrollUp 20s linear 1s infinite;
            /* Adjust the duration as needed */
        }

        /* Keyframes for scrolling animation */
        @keyframes scrollUp {
            0% {
                transform: translateY(100%);
            }

            100% {
                transform: translateY(-100%);
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="loadDoc()">
    <div id="demo">
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>


getNotifs.php . PLEASE IGNORE FIRST FEW LINES they are used for just checking I am able to connect to database or not

<?php
define('WEB_ID','l-cbz01');
require('wp-config.php');
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
// failed
// die with an error
if (!$link) {
    // send HTTP/500 status code first
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
    echo "<html><head><title>Failed at " .WEB_ID. "</title></head><body><pre>";
    echo "Web server: ". WEB_ID .  PHP_EOL;
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
 
 
mysqli_close($link); 

?>

<!-- NOW START LOOKING FOR stm_posts and build a list of news items with the respective links to the posts-->

    <?php 


        $categories = [
                 'technology' => 'Announcements'];
        foreach($categories as $key => $category):
            $query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'stm_works',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order' => 'DESC',
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'posts_per_page' => 15,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
             );
            $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    ?>
    <div class="announcement-container">
            <div class="announcement-text">         
        <section id="<?php echo $key ?>" class="col-sm-6 section">
        <h3 class="title" align="center"> <?php echo  $query->query['category_name'] ; ?> </h3>   
       <?php    
            if ( $query->have_posts()):
                while ( $query->have_posts() ):
                    $query->the_post();
        ?> 
          
          
             <h5><img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/newicon.png" width="30" height="30"/><a href=" <?php the_permalink() ?> " target="_blank"> <?php the_title() ?> </a></h5>
               
    <?php       
            endwhile;
                echo "<hr />";
                wp_reset_postdata();
            else:
                echo "<h6> Sorry! No post has been found of this type. </h6>";
                echo "<hr />";
            endif;
    ?>
        <hr />
        </section>
        </div>

</div>
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
***************** END OF PHP **************

